# Run Rake task in parallel using different parameters

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rake, selenium-grid

I've a scenario where data has to be loaded from different input files. So my current approach is to execute the loader script using selenium grid in 10 different systems. Each system will have their own input files and other information like PORT, IP_ADDRESS for grid will also be passed in rake task itself. Now, these information will be saved in an excel file and code has to be written to build n number of rake task with different environment variables and then execute them all together.

I'm unable to come up with a way where all the task will be created automatically and executed as well.

I know it has to be done using 'parallel_test' gem or rake multi-task feature but don't know how exactly this can be achieved. Any other approach is also welcomed.